# Format string and deleting special characters using ASCII code doesn't work (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, string, format, frontend, ascii

Im trying to format any given string using ASCII code for reference. The format must delete any special character except numbers, "-" or "_" and spaces. Here's the code:

```js
 function FormatString(sentence) {
        result = new String();
        j = 0;
        sentence = sentence.toUpperCase();
        i = 0;

        while(i < sentence.length) {
            if (
                (sentence[i]>=65 && sentence[i]<=90) ||
                (sentence[i]>=48 && sentence[j]<=57) ||
                sentence[i]==32 || sentence[i]==45
            ) {
                sentence[j] = result[i];
                j = j + 1;
            }
            i = i + 1;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

and then call the function

```
console.log(FormatString('No running in the hallways!!!'))
```

the output should be "No running in the hallways"

Comment: At first, `sentence` still contains the characters, not the codepoints, also, strings are immutable, you can't change a single character in a string. Take a look at [RegExps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), they're what you need for the task.

Comment: @Teemu I think I understand what you say, so, what should I change or do?

Comment: `sentence[j] = result[i];` this seems backwards.  `result += sentence[j]`?  Also in your if you have `sentence[j]<=57` where `sentence[i]<=57` should probably be.

Comment: @James it still returns an empty string, even tough I assign the formatted sentence to the result variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that using [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) would be the best way to solve your problem, I am assuming you want to use ASCII comparison for a reason.

The following solution works:

```js
function FormatString (sentence) {
    let result = "";

    const uppercaseSentence = sentence.toUpperCase();

    for (let i=0; i<uppercaseSentence.length; i++) {
        let cc = uppercaseSentence.charCodeAt(i);
        if ((cc>=65 && cc<=90) || (cc>=48 && cc<=57) || cc==32 || cc==45) {
            result += sentence[i];
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

I am reporting below your function and commenting what was wrong with it:

```js
function FormatString(sentence) {
    
    // you are declaring a global variable here.
    // let result = ... or var result = ... makes it local
    // In javascript you can use an string literal `""` in place of new String()
    result = new String();
    
    // again a global variable
    j = 0;
    
    // you are chaning the passed parameter to an uppercase string
    // you lost the original string now
    sentence = sentence.toUpperCase();
    
    // again a global variable
    i = 0;

    // nothing wron with the while loop, only the for loop is more concise in
    // this case
    while(i < sentence.length) {
        
        if (
            // sentence[i] is a streing with length 1 and it returns false if
            // compared with a number. Use instead sentence.charCodeAt(i) which
            // returns the ASCII code of the i-th character
            (sentence[i]>=65 && sentence[i]<=90) ||
                                // there is a j here in place of an i
            (sentence[i]>=48 && sentence[j]<=57) ||
            sentence[i]==32 || sentence[i]==45
        ) {
            // you can't assign single characters in javascript
            // what you want to do is result += sentence[i],
            // but remember that sentence is now all uppercase and so will be 
            // result!
            sentence[j] = result[i];
            j = j + 1;
        }
        i = i + 1;
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped a lot and now I understand the exercise, and thank you for the bonus explanation on the original function!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `string.replace` with regex will help in your need:

```
const regex = /[-_]/g
"afasf-afsaf_fafa".replace(regex,''); //"afasfafsaffafa"
```

Comment: thank you for your response, but "_" and "-" should be left intact, the ones I'm trying to format are every other special character, and I need to use the code given because it is an exercise

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question